# Xamarin.Forms: Move to .NET Standard

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms project targets `PCL` `profile 259`. I recently read a lot of moving to .NET Standard, but it looks very painful to do.

Currently I develop in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. But will give VS 2017 a try soon.

My solution consists of:

- Common PCL library
- Android specific project
- iOS specific project

**My Questions:**

1. How can I convert from Profile 259 to latest .NET Standard?
2. Is there some official converson guide from Xamarin / Microsoft Team already available?
3. My Xamarin.Forms Android and iOS Apps are built in VSTS. Does VSTS support .NET Standard or would I end up in build errors?

Thanks in advance for any good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a PCL to .NET Standard you just need to go to the Properties of your PCL and select Target .NET Standard Platform

[image]

Then create a project.json file, if it didn't already create one for you and insert the following.

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.4.192-pre2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+wpa81"
    }
  }
}
```

You need the imports to allow non .NET Standard libraries to be added.

In VS 2017 it gets different. While the above will continue to work, you can have a full .NET Standard library as a csproj (no longer an xproj), and have it happily work with Xamarin.

However, there is no automatic conversion (that I know of), so what I normally do, is edit the csproj and completely replace it with the following. Just delete everything in that file and put the following.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.3</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>MyLibraryName</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>MyLibraryName</PackageId>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You will then have to add your references and NuGet packages manually, again. With the PackageTargetFallback, this line is similar to the imports in project.json.

In regards to VSTS, I know that the first method with VS2015 works just fine, as I have done it myself. The VS2017 method should work with VSTS, however I haven't personally tried that just yet.

Comment: Wiping out the .csproj causes the build actions on XAML files to be lost. If you want to tweak an existing project, adding the `PackageTargetFallback` element is the key.

Comment: Rather than use that link in the project property sheet, it'd be better to follow this walkthrough instead: https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk - thats what I mentioned in the post, in the second section, when referring to VS2017. The first section is for VS2015. I go through it more detail here for VS2017: https://xamarinhelp.com/visual-studio-2017-net-standard-xamarin/